# bitmap image gets stretched inside canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am working on an application. where i use canvas and draw bitmap image inside it.

i get video as bytes with resolution (e.g 800 x 600 ) as width and height
i convert it to bitmap images with same width and height.

After converting the bitmap images i call the canvas, i create a destination rectangle. and call this method

canvas.createbitmap(bitmap, src rect, destination rect );

Everything works fine. the bitmap image is fit into the destination rectangle.

- But if i rotate the image 90 % , i need to show the image in rotated angle. But i cannot get it done. the image is stretched and fit into the destination rectangle.

I want to achieve and see the rotated image as it is..inside the canvas. I dont want the stretched image.

Kindly let me know how to add the bitmap image without re-sizing to fit into the destination rectangle.

```
     Bitmap bmp = null
     byte[] data = videoInfo.getData();
     ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
     buf.rewind();
     Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(videoInfo.getWidth(), videoInfo.getHeight(),  Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
     bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buf);     

      int dstLeft = miLeft;
      int dstTop = miTop;
      int dstRight = dstLeft + miWidth;
      int dstBottom = dstTop + miHeight;
      Rect dst = new Rect(dstLeft, dstTop, dstRight, dstBottom);

      Rect src = null;     

     canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);
```

Comment: pls post the code you're using for creating of `Rect`s and rotation of the `Bitmap`

Comment: @blipinsk I have added the code . Please support

Comment: and the rotation code?

Comment: @blipinsk. rotation of image is not code...i rotate the image 90% and send it. I havent written any code. for that.